# Error occurs on Debug, but not on Start New Instance, and only with a Content Reference in another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, project-reference

I have a Visual Studio 2010, XNA 4.0 game solution. Call it "Game". It has a project named "Game" with an associated content project named "GameContent". I also have created a second project in the solution named "LevelEditor" with an associated content project named "LevelEditorContent".

Game and LevelEditor can both load content from their own content projects, no problem. I decided to see if I could get LevelEditor to load content from GameContent, though, so I added a content reference in LevelEditor to GameContent.

Now, when I click Debug or hit F5, Game crashes with a FileNotFound error on one of its pieces of content. If I remove the content reference from LevelEditor, Game works again. I have no idea why. Game is the only startup project.

To make it even stranger, if I right-click on the Game project in Solution Explorer, select Debug, then "Start New Instance", Game runs fine - no FileNotFound error at all - regardless of whether LevelEditor has that content reference or not.

Why would a content reference in a DIFFERENT project screw up Game's ability to load its content? And what's different between F5/Debug and Start New Instance that would make the error occur using the former but not the latter?

Comment: Did you check the DLL of GameContent project is located in the debug folder of LevelEditor project?

Comment: Guillaume - I just checked - neither LevelEditor nor Game has a DLL for GameContent in their bin\x86\debug folder.  GameContent doesn't contain any code though, just image and xml files.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your issue. Try to read all the details of that exception and see where it tries to find the file and why it doesn't find it. Check that ContentManager.RootDirectory and Environment.CurrentDirectory are correct, and that all the content is built properly. Does anything change if you do a Rebuild?

Comment: The ContentManager.RootDirectory and Environment.CurrentDirectory are definitely correct.

Comment: However, I discovered that when LevelEditor has a reference to GameContent, a rebuild puts GameContent's output in LevelEditor's bin\x86\debug folder and REMOVES it from Game's bin\x86\debug folder. I don't understand why the content would get built to a different location based on whether or not that Content Reference is in place.